# How do I freely warp points using Canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-canvas

I want to "warp" specific points in a image, similar to the Warp tool in Photoshop, but programmatically in JavaScript, (or Node.js) specifically Canvas.

Example image warping in photoshop

[image: 1]

I've seen threads about using [quad warping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660521/html5-canvas-drawimage-using-points) or [arbitrary warping effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008771/create-image-warping-effect-in-webgl-three-js), but I don't know how to manipulate specific points or where I would even start.

In a perfect world, what I'm looking for is a function that can take a x,y coordinate of a image and warp in to another x, y coordinate. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what have you tried? can you show some code of where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: I don't know where to start with something like this. Could you help me?

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... stackoverflow is not the best resource to get recommendations